# Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting following error while using CreateContext:

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Below is my code:

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react'

export const CartContext =  createContext({});

const CartProvider = (props) => {

  const addItemToCartHandler = item => {};
  const removeItemFromCartHandler = id => {};

  const CartContext = {
    items: [],
    totalAmount: 0,
    addItem: addItemToCartHandler,
    removeItem: removeItemFromCartHandler,
  }

  return (
  <CartContext.Provider value = {CartContext}>
      {props.children}
  </CartContext.Provider>
  )  
}
    
export default CartProvider;
```

Below is my app.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Cart from './components/Cart/Cart/Cart';
import Header from './components/Layout/Header/Header'
import Meals from './components/Meals/Meals/Meals'
import CartProvider, { CartContext } from './store/CartProvider';


function App() {
  const [cartIsShown, setCartIsShown] = useState(false);

  const showCartHandler = () => {
    setCartIsShown(true);
  }

  const hideCartHandler = () => {
    setCartIsShown(false);
  }

  return (
    <CartProvider>
      {cartIsShown && <Cart onClose = {hideCartHandler}/>}
      <Header onShowCart = {showCartHandler} />
      <main>
        <Meals />
      </main>
    </CartProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare this

```
export const CartContext =  createContext({});
```

And below

```
const CartContext = {
    items: [],
    totalAmount: 0,
    addItem: addItemToCartHandler,
    removeItem: removeItemFromCartHandler,
  }
```

And then you use it, rename one of them, otherwise CartContext.Provider is the object you declared

For example:

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react'

export const CartContext =  createContext({});

const CartProvider = (props) => {

  const addItemToCartHandler = item => {};
  const removeItemFromCartHandler = id => {};

  const DefaultCartContext = {
    items: [],
    totalAmount: 0,
    addItem: addItemToCartHandler,
    removeItem: removeItemFromCartHandler,
  }

  return (
  <CartContext.Provider value = {DefaultCartContext}>
      {props.children}
  </CartContext.Provider>
  )  
}
    
export default CartProvider;
```